# Generate a random number onclick (working) and use that to display a random message (not working) in a cute webapp I'm making for my wife, new to JS

Tags: javascript, random, onclick

I've been working on this webapp for my wife, it's very simple, basically when she clicks on a button a random "You're awesome" style message will pop up.

My first implementation was a simple button that when pressed, a message and picture would show up, it worked perfectly. (Code below)

```js
 
document.getElementById("paulaBtn").addEventListener("click", displayMsg);

const unicorn = document.createElement("img");
unicorn.setAttribute("src", "unicorn.jpg");

function displayMsg() {
    document.getElementById("displayMsg").innerHTML = "the most beautiful unicorn in the world!",
    document.getElementById("displayMsg").appendChild(unicorn);
}
```

Then I tried to make it more complicated by generating a random number (rdmInt) when she clicks the button, and using an if else loop to check rdmInt against numbers and display a message based on the number.

I am new to JS and I've spent several hours reading and learning but I haven't managed to get it to work, I'm guessing I'm missing something silly.

The random number is correctly generated onclick (I can see it on console.log) so the problem has to do with checking it against the other numbers I guess. Thanks in advance for any help and tips.

```js
JAVASCRIPT

function rndInt() {
    let rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    console.log(rndInt)
};
let x = rndInt;

const unicorn = document.createElement("img");
unicorn.setAttribute("src", "unicorn.jpg");

const art = document.createElement("img");
art.setAttribute("src", "artist.gif");    


if (x === 0) {
    function displayMsg() {
        document.getElementById("displayMsg").innerHTML = "the most beautiful unicorn in the world!",
        document.getElementById("displayMsg").appendChild(unicorn);
    }console.log(rndInt)
} else if (x === 1) {
    function displayArt() {
        document.getElementById("displayArt").innerHTML = "an awesome artist",
        document.getElementById("displayArt").appendChild(art);
    }
}
```

```css
CSS

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 14vh 10vh 60vh auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('back.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.back{
    background-image: url("back.jpg");
    height: max-content;
}

h1 {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: pink;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 4vh;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

#reset {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    border: none;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

img{
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#displayMsg{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#displayArt{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

  a,
  button {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
.paulaBtn{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .paulaBtn li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(197, 173, 181);
  }
  
  .paulaBtn a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

#paulaBtn{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: none;
}
.button{
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3rem;
}
.button {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Paula</h1>


    <div onclick="rndInt()" class="paulaBtn">
        <button id="paulaBtn">Paula is</button>
        </div>
        
    <p id="displayMsg"></p>
    <p id="displayArt"></p>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't give your function the same name as your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes I made are only in the JS code.

In order for your code to work correctly, you must enter everything in the function that you call when the button is pressed

```js
function rndInt() {
    let rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    console.log(rndInt)

    let x = rndInt;

    const unicorn = document.createElement("img");
    unicorn.setAttribute("src", "unicorn.jpg");

    const art = document.createElement("img");
    art.setAttribute("src", "artist.gif");

    var msgEl = document.getElementById("displayMsg");
    msgEl.innerHTML = "";

    var artEl = document.getElementById("displayArt")
    artEl.innerHTML = "";

    if (x === 0) {
        msgEl.innerHTML = "the most beautiful unicorn in the world!";
        msgEl.appendChild(unicorn);
    } else if (x === 1) {
        artEl.innerHTML = "an awesome artist";
        artEl.appendChild(art);
    }
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 14vh 10vh 60vh auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('back.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.back {
    background-image: url("back.jpg");
    height: max-content;
}

h1 {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: pink;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 4vh;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

#reset {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    border: none;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

img {
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#displayMsg {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#displayArt {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

a,
button {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.paulaBtn {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
}

.paulaBtn li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(197, 173, 181);
}

.paulaBtn a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#paulaBtn {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: none;
}

.button {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3rem;
}

.button {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Paula</h1>


<div onclick="rndInt()" class="paulaBtn">
    <button id="paulaBtn">Paula is</button>
</div>

<p id="displayMsg"></p>
<p id="displayArt"></p>
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much, that worked perfectly. So the main problem was that everything was outside the funcion? Could I ask why was it necessary to add var msgEl and var artEL?

Comment: Not necessarily! These are variable names and you can change them as you wish. But this reduces the amount of code and makes it easier to read. I'm glad I was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Have an array of messages you want:

```
const messages = [
“...”,
“...”,
“...”
]

const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length) // Get random index 

console.log(messages[randIndex]) // Get random message from messages array
```